# How can you draw candlestick charts on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, charts, candlestick-chart

I am new to Quartz, and I would like to draw a candlestick chart in iOS, but I don't know how.

How can I draw charts like this? Are there any good examples for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Plot may be able to do it. If not, it's probably a pretty easy thing to add to the Core Plot library.

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Comment: I just found that there is a example code in CorePlot named "AAPLot" It seems like the Candlestick plots we are looking at in Stock Market....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [SwiftCharts](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts), there are 2 candle sticks examples ready to use - one interactive and other not-interactive (with less overhead, in case you don't need interactivity)

(Disclosure: I'm the author)